# How to find a record from MongoDB where the date field is more than a month older in Node JS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, date

I have a date of joining field as doj (type : Date) in my MongoDB collection. I want to find the records of all employees who joined more than a month before from today. However it is giving any record where the doj is just even one day greater than the one month old date from today. I am not getting the one month older doj from today. Please help me with the mistakes that I am making. 
I am using the following code :

```
    var dt = new Date();
    dt.setMonth(dt.getMonth() - 1);
    collection.find({doj: {$gt:dt}}, function(error, docs) {
        docs.forEach(function (doc) {
            console.log("DOJ = "+ doc.doj);
        }    
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want records with date of joining **older** then one month ago, you should query for `{doj: {$lt:dt}}`

Comment: but I need to ensure that the difference between the dates are more than a month? Does it start January as 0 or 1?

Comment: the line `dt.setMonth(dt.getMonth() - 1)` in your code will make sure of that, `dt` will be exactly one month ago, and all docs that have `doj` less then `dt` will be returned. Months start at 0, but don't worry, the `Date.setMonth` function will handle January as expected.

Comment: In my application dt.setMonth(dt.getMonth() - 1) statement gives me 4th Jan 2017 which is one month older date. But applying the {$lt: dt} logic returning 2016-11-25T00:00:00.000Z, 2016-11-15T00:00:00.000Z and 2017-01-01T00:00:00.000Z , how come it is returning both Dec 2016 and February 2017 dates ?

Comment: Wrong reporting. It was my bad I did not notice correctly. Your answer is working perfectly.